# NSIS Uninstaller custom components with /COMPONENTSONLYONCUSTOM

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I'm new at this and maybe is pretty easy and im just missing some problem with syntax and NSIS.

Im buildig a installer/uninstaller and using InstType Default and InstType /COMPONENTSONLYONCUSTOM for the former.

My problem is, I can't make it work the same way for the uninstaller. I'm able to create different options to select components for the uninstaller but I cant make it so the components only show when the custom option is selected.

What am I missing?

Tried using stuff like InstType un./COMPONENTSONLYONCUSTOM or similar but didn't work

```
LangString instType ${LANG_ENGLISH} "Default"

InstType $(instType)
InstType /COMPONENTSONLYONCUSTOM  

InstType un.$(instType) 
InstType /COMPONENTSONLYONCUSTOM   un.$(instType)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InstType` switches only apply to the installer. I'll try to add uninstaller support to v3.10...